# extjs 4.0 retrieve grid values

Tags: grid, extjs4

The code below is for getting a Json string for the selected rows in a grid.
However this feels rather clumsy or is the way to go for extjs 4?

```
var json = "[";
var selrows = g.getView().getSelectionModel().getSelection();
for (var r=0; r<selrows.length; r++) {
    var selrow = selrows[r];
    json += "{";
    for (var f=0; f<selrow.fields.length; f++) {
        var n = selrow.fields.items[f].name;
        var v = selrow.data[n];
        json += "'" + n + "' : '" + v + "',";
    }
    json += "},";
}  
json += "]";
alert(json);
```

In Firebug I see a json-alike representation of the selrow var but I can't seem to get hold of it in javascript.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
json = Ext.JSON.encode(g.getView().getSelectionModel().getSelection().map(function(e){ return e.data; }));

alert(json);
```